# Select All Field (if field not exist, make field with null value)

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have a table with this field and condition

```
table cc_queue_detail
ticket_id    field_name_id             data_content
1            category_ticket_1         33
1            category_ticket_2         44
2            category_ticket_1         55
```

I want to select for table cc_queue_detail and make them into like this:

```
ticket_id   category_ticket_1    category_ticket_2
1           33                   44
2           55
```

i haved tried this query, but its only selected with the ticket_id 1

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a1.ticket_id AS 'ticket_id',
a2.data_content AS 'category_ticket_1',
a3.data_content AS 'category_ticket_2'
FROM 
cc_queue_detail a1
JOIN cc_queue_detail a2 ON a1.ticket_id = a2.ticket_id
JOIN cc_queue_detail a3 ON a1.ticket_id = a3.ticket_id
WHERE a2.field_name_id = "category_ticket_1"
AND a3.field_name_id = "category_ticket_2"
```

result query:

```
ticket_id   category_ticket_1    category_ticket_2
1           33                   44
```

i tried change  `AND a3.field_name_id = "category_ticket_2"` into `OR a3.field_name_id = "category_ticket_2"` but it not work.

can someone help me to fixed this?

Comment: Read about "pivot".

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is you're using an `INNER JOIN` (`JOIN` for short) between the same `ticket_id` of your `cc_queue_detail` table `a1`, and two different sets of rows from your second and third instance of the `cc_queue_detail` table, `a2` and `a3`. This basically is saying the `ticket_id` has to match between `a1`, `a2`, and `a3` always, but because of your `WHERE` clause, that's not possible, since `a2` and `a3` are different sets of rows from your `cc_queue_detail` table.

You'll want to use an `OUTER JOIN`, such as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (`LEFT JOIN` for short) to accomplish your goal, something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a1.ticket_id AS 'ticket_id',
    a2.data_content AS 'category_ticket_1',
    a3.data_content AS 'category_ticket_2'
FROM cc_queue_detail a1
LEFT JOIN cc_queue_detail a2 
    ON a1.ticket_id = a2.ticket_id
    AND a2.field_name_id = "category_ticket_1"
LEFT JOIN cc_queue_detail a3 
    ON a1.ticket_id = a3.ticket_id
    AND a3.field_name_id = "category_ticket_2"
```

Now you'll get all rows back from `a1`, your entire `cc_queue_detail` table, and where there isn't a match between the other instances of the table (`a2` and `a3`) there will be `NULL` values.

Answer (score 1):

An `OUTER JOIN` would work nicely here with a `GROUP BY` roll up:

```
SELECT a1.ticket_id,
       MAX(a2.data_content) AS category_ticket_1,
       MAX(a3.data_content) AS category_ticket_2
  FROM cc_queue_detail a1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN cc_queue_detail a2 ON a1.ticket_id = a2.ticket_id AND a2.field_name_id = 'category_ticket_1'
       LEFT OUTER JOIN cc_queue_detail a3 ON a1.ticket_id = a3.ticket_id AND a3.field_name_id = 'category_ticket_2'
 GROUP BY a1.ticket_id
```

Any values that do not exist will return as `NULL`.

Comment: dude, i try your answer, and the result is:
ticket_id      category_ticket_1      category_ticket_2
(NULL)         (NULL)                       55
1                  33                              44

but, i change the RIGHT to LEFT, the result suit with what i expected

ticket_id      category_ticket_1      category_ticket_2
1                  33                              44
2                  55                              (NULL)

Thanks a lot, dude!